# App hangs after UIActionSheet button clicked

Tags: ios, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I am trying to use a UIAction sheet to confirm a user’s action.  The log prints fine... but the app hangs and shows the lightened circle in the middle like when you do a UIAlert view.  I’m sure its something simple... but can’t seem to find it.

```
-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender
{
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Reset Player" otherButtonTitles:nil];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;

[popupQuery showInView:self.view];



}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Destructive Button Clicked");
}
else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    NSLog(@"Cancel Clicked");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this handler instead of `clickedButtonAtIndex`:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: This still does that same thing

Comment: I checked and indeed, a note in clickedButtonAtIndex states "The receiver is automatically dismissed after this method is invoked" so it should be equivalent--sorry!

Comment: I haven’t fixed it yet.. but its because I’m calling it from a UIAlertView I’m sure.

Comment: Yes I changed it to didDismissWithButtonIndex for the alert view and it fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please release the UIActionSheet i.e where you create

```
[popupQuery release];
```

Comment: I’m using ARC that’s why I didn’t have that.